# Indexing weeks in MILP: better to have 12 weeks, or 3 months at 4 weeks each?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

As a general rule, when building decision variables, is it computationally preferable to index along fewer dimensions instead of more when the count of permutations are identical?

For context, I'm building a production optimization model on a 12 week horizon.  Production requirements are given at the monthly level for the next 3 months (presumed exactly 4 weeks / 28 days per month).

For ease of building these monthly production constraints, I'm indexing my decision variables along both week and month dimensions [week = 1:4, month = 1:3].  Would it be computationally beneficial to just index along weeks 1:12, then apply monthly production constraints on weeks 1:4, 5:8, 9:12 separately?

Comment: A variable is a variable. The solver does not know about higher dimensions of the modelling-tool and internal reasoning will be 1d-based. In regards to modelling, those things can make some difference (efficient example: striding-based like Eigen or numpy; inefficient: Java -> array of arrays), but are irrelevant in regards to overhead most of the time and modelling-ease-of-use is what i would prefer. Storage-order (2d: row-major vs. col-major) can lead to observable overhead in some slow-modelling use-cases but most peoples models are probably solver-time dominated.

Comment: Thanks.  That was my initial thought.  It's much easier to index with weeks/months for the purposes of building constraints, so I'll stay with that.